# How to change Azure App Services Github workflow deployment environment name

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

[image]

When you create an app there's no option to customize this, it's just there by default.

This matters because sometimes I don't want github actions to say that I'm deploying to "production", I want it to say I'm deploying to "development". But if I change this property manually, I'll get an error in github actions saying: `Error: Deployment Failed with Error: Error: Publish profile is invalid for app-name and slot-name provided. Provide correct publish profile credentials for app.` But then as soon as it's changed back the deployment works again, so I need to find a way to change this property in Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always the main slot of the webapp is called production, there is no way to change it.

Comment: is there any way for a single app service instance to have multiple environments?

Comment: yes, you will have to use deployment slots,
you can have one slot per environment in a single app service.

Comment: Did you find this in the documentation somewhere? I was looking for the name of the main slot but it's nowhere mentioned. Except in the Azure CLI documentation under flag `--target-slot`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment/slot?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-deployment-slot-swap-optional-parameters